# Dell xps 13 9310 internal microphone don't work

Tags: microphone

I spent several hours with Dell support and we could not find a solution to this problem.  The BIOS is the latest 2.2.0  All microphone connection specifications are correct and there are no visible errors.  Does anyone have a proposal?  
Thanks 
 Josef

Comment: I would argue this is a *good* thing, as the audio quality of most internal microphones is absolutely awful. That said, there's almost no actionable information in your question to offer an answer with. Can you [edit] your question to include: (1) the version of Ubuntu you are running (2) the output of `lsusb` (3) the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia` (4) a more complete description of what you mean by "don't work"

Comment: Yes, you are right with respect to internal microphones. The mic on my headset is much better. It is only a question of personal comfort

Comment: Finally, Dell took responsibility and exchanged the microphone for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04

lsusb

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:672a Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Edge
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:533c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lshw

*-usb:2
description: Video
product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
vendor: CN03GGY48LG0011UBB5HA00
physical id: 6
bus info: usb@3:6
version: 5.29
capabilities: usb-2.01
configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
*-multimedia
description: Multimedia audio controller
product: Intel Corporation
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 1f.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
version: 20
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci latency=64
resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:187 memory:60531d8000-60531dbfff memory:6053000000-60530fffff